# Variable Is Not Setting Globally

Tags: jquery, function, variables, global-variables

I'm not sure how much StackOverflow will be able to help with this (my code is quite long), but I'll try to phrase this in a way that might provide a broader learning opportunity that's not just specific to my code.

I'm trying to use the value of a variable `ActualAnswer` (set as 1.2 in the function `LikeTermsCombiner2()`) globally

------Broad Overview of My Code As It Currently Stands (THIS WORKS)-----

```
function LikeTermsCombiner2(){ 
    //Lines 75-5621 in the JSFiddle Link

  var ActualAnswer = $(ExpressionToCombine).find(".Answer").clone(); 
    //Variable defined @ Line 2991
    //Sets variable to 1.2

    $(".Answer" + ParenthExpressionID).html(ActualAnswer); 
    //Every element with a particular class is replaced by ActualAnswer...successfully replaces that class with 1.2

}
```

------My Attempt to make ActualAnswer a global variable for use in other functions (CORRUPTS CODE; ActualAnswer no longer generates)-----

```
var GlobalVariableTest; 

function LikeTermsCombiner2(){ //Lines 75-5621

  var ActualAnswer = $(ExpressionToCombine).find(".Answer").clone(); //VARIABLE DEFINED @ Line 2991 

GlobalVariableTest = $(ActualAnswer).text();

    $(".Answer" + ParenthExpressionID).html(ActualAnswer); //CLASS REPLACED WITH VALUE OF ActualAnswer

}

alert(GlobalVariableTest);
```

Here's the full JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2x7049bs/133/

(I never anticipated sharing this so apologies in advance for the poor formatting.)

Comment: Do you call `LikeTermsCombiner2()` ?  As it is you have `declare var; define function; check var;` so the var will still be default

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, sorry, I should have clarified. The function does get called later on in the code.

Comment: "later on in the code" - before or after you call `alert(GlobalVariableTest)` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m before `alert(GlobalVariableTest)`